# On-send enabled by default for Office 365?

Tags: outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-on-send-addins?tabs=classic) say:

> By default, on-send functionality is disabled. Administrators can enable on-send by running Exchange Online PowerShell cmdlets.

This does not appear to be true for Office 365. Our on-send functionality is working fine without having had to enable anything. We've tried this with multiple (new) tenants. Are the docs outdated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On-send functionality is disabled by default on JSVVM, but enabled by default on OWA React. That means, it is enabled by default for Office 365.

The Documentation should be updated to be more specific.